# pivot_table() doesn't display all values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to display a table in Python 3 using `pivot_table()`. I used this piece of code:

```
words = ["health"]
mydata = get_sept_data(words)
print (mydata) 
pd.pivot_table(mydata, values=["commentCount", "dislikeCount","likeCount", "viewCount"], aggfunc='sum',index='Keyword')
```

My problem is that I am only getting `commentCount` and `viewCounts` columns instead of having 4 columns. `mydata` contains a total of 15 columns. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: In this doc : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html they seems to use column where you use values

Comment: Can you please update an expected output for your dataframe?

Comment: I would expect to have a table with 5 columns; first for kewrods, then commentCount, dislikeCount,likeCount, viewCount.  so dislikeCount and LikeCount are missing but when I print mydata, these values exist